# high ping over 12s to wireless-n router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ping

I have a 2.4/5GHz wireless-N router, for quite sometime and recently starting up again I have experienced ping over 12000ms:

```
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5770 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4914 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4248 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=3454 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2567 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=2084 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=2474 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=2041 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=1124 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=289 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=31.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=8.84 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=147 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=23.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=35.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=349 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=287 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=34.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=1576 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=919 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=2027 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=3209 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=2569 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=2862 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=1999 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=1367 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=619 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=1274 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=738 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=988 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=814 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=561 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=968 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=569 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=523 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=912 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=2906 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=2192 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=1324 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=1010 ms
```

I have tried every channel 1-13, changing the speed setting between 300mbps, 145mbps and 54mbps with lower encryption, all which are fruitless

At first, it was on channel 1, 300mpbs, the high ping started showing, after which I switched to 12/13 300mbps, problem persisted, so I changed to 6 @ 300mpbs and it was fine, now it started up again,

I have swapped between 5, 6, 7 and even lowering the speed, but nothing is helping

2 other wifi networks are in the area, 1 weak (channel 1) and other almost not visible (channel 112/113 if I recall correctly, yes 112/113)

This is a consistent problem, happens at 1am or 3pm, no matter time or router load!

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Hard wired connections, i.e. with LAN cable shows NO sign of high latency, so hard wired connections are NOT affected at all

This is also not explicitly happening at a certain time (1AM/ 3PM) as assumed in the comments, last night when I made this question it occured, but now while I'm editing it, no problem at all, the problem occurs at random!

Comment: So what else is happening at 1 am and 3 pm? Do you have some scheduled tasks running? Is there any other activity on your local network?

Comment: What sort of ping times do you get with a hard-wired connection? Do you have access to another computer you can also use to check?

Comment: @DavidPostill please check update

Comment: @AndrewMorton please check update

Comment: @Cybex USB 3 can interfere with 2.4GHz wireless signals. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Don't test 2.4GHz with any channel width other than 20MHz. What country are you in?

Answer (score 2):

Could be:

- Failing equipment
- 2.4Ghz noise. Even if you can see only two SSIDs it doesnt mean the spectrum is clear. A microwave oven can cause chaos but you will not see it on scans!

If at all possible, move to 5Ghz. If not test with another laptop, if that improves things then you should upgrade the computers NIC.

Lastly, if this is a laptop, move the lid back and forward when it happens, the antenna running through the hinge can wear out.

Comment: Any suggestions what i can use to test 2.4/5Ghz band interference, this is an occurance with all wifi devices, thus it is noise or faulty hardware

Comment: Switch to 5Ghz, if theres noise in the spectrum around 2.4 it'll fix immediately when you change over to 5Ghz.

Comment: If you have a noise issue, immediately switch to narrower channels. It almost never makes sense to try to use 40Mhz channels on 2.4GHz unless you're in the wilderness.